# How to check for 4way handshake in ivs files?

Tags: wireless-networking

There are many tutorials how to search in pcap files for the 4way handshake in wireshark (search for the "eapol").

**Q:** But how can I search for these in .ivs files? Or ivs files doesn't contain these informations?

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7080/how-to-check-for-4way-handshake-in-ivs-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IVS files contain something called 'initialization vectors' and these are what are used in WEP(wired equivalent privacy) networks. If you manage to catch enough of these you can then recover the key as it leaks somehow. There is also an in depth vido on how WEP networks and such work found over on securitytube: http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=view&groupId=9. Hope this helps